# angular validator to restrict special characters in filename while upload

Tags: javascript, angular

I am not sure if we can apply validator to a input type="file",All I am trying to do is show error message "special characters not allowed" if user tries to upload a file name containing special characters. But the following code not working as expected. It shows error message in all cases .

```
 <input #elementFileInput id="fileSelector" type="file" accept=".zip formControlName="filename" />
<div class="validation-message-container"
*ngIf="!form.controls['filename'].valid && form.controls['filename'].dirty">
<i class="fa fa-info-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i>
<span *ngIf="form.controls['filename'].errors?.pattern">special characters not allowed
</span>
{{form.controls['filename'].errors?.pattern|json}}
</div>
```

component.ts code:

```
pattern = new RegExp(/^[^*|\"<>{}`\\()';@&$]+$/);

this.form = this.fb.group({
start_date: new FormControl(this.project.start_date, { validators: [Validators.required] }),
budget: new FormControl(''),
filename:  new FormControl('', { validators: [Validators.pattern(this.pattern)] }),
})
```

here is what I see on my screen(even though file name does not contain special characters)

[image]

Comment: The value you provided does not match the regex pattern you specified, so it fails.
https://regex101.com/r/MWR2r6/1
You have to fix your regex

Answer (score 0):

```
/^[ A-Za-z0-9_@./#&+-]*$/
```

Try this Regex

Comment: can you please confirm if it is trying to validate filepath or filename? i would like to validate just the filename and not the whole path

Comment: Its only for filename
It will allow alphanumeric and special characters also

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by using custom validator as on uploading we get object and not just filename, and it was trying to match with "c://fakePath/kjfkd.zip